# MacOS : No Japanese input method

Tags: macos, input-source, japanese

I have added Japanese as a favourite languages in preferences :

[image]

However, in the Input Methods panel, the Japanese input method seems to be missing :

[image]

How can I fix that / add the Japanese IME ?

Note : I don't want to install Google's or Mr.third party's Japanese IME. I want to enable Apple's native Japanese IME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common problem.  Try a Safe Boot.  If that doesn't work, try the fixes in Apple's article on the topic.  See [this page](http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2017/12/macos-high-sierra-missing-input-sources.html).